# Template classes in C++

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

Hi I am getting the error message `error: expected initializer before '<' token` every time i declare a function in the code below.  I am not very familiar with templates in c++ so this error is really throwing me.  I already tried to use the typename keyword but it didnt work.  Any help would be great.

BinarySearchTree.h

```
        #ifndef BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H_
        #define BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H_

        #include "dsexceptions.h"
        #include <iostream.h>       // For NULL

          // Binary node and forward declaration because g++ does
          // not understand nested classes.
        template <class Comparable>
        class BinarySearchTree;

        template <class Comparable>
        class BinaryNode
        {
            Comparable element;
            BinaryNode *left;
            BinaryNode *right;

            BinaryNode( const Comparable & theElement, BinaryNode *lt, BinaryNode *rt )
              : element( theElement ), left( lt ), right( rt ) { }
            friend class BinarySearchTree<Comparable>;
        };


        // BinarySearchTree class
        //
        // CONSTRUCTION: with ITEM_NOT_FOUND object used to signal failed finds
        //
        // ******************PUBLIC OPERATIONS*********************
        // void insert( x )       --> Insert x
        // void remove( x )       --> Remove x
        // Comparable find( x )   --> Return item that matches x
        // Comparable findMin( )  --> Return smallest item
        // Comparable findMax( )  --> Return largest item
        // boolean isEmpty( )     --> Return true if empty; else false
        // void makeEmpty( )      --> Remove all items
        // void printTree( )      --> Print tree in sorted order

        template <class Comparable>
        class BinarySearchTree
        {
          public:
            explicit BinarySearchTree( const Comparable & notFound );
            BinarySearchTree( const BinarySearchTree & rhs );
            ~BinarySearchTree( );

            const Comparable & findMin( ) const;
            const Comparable & findMax( ) const;
            const Comparable & find( const Comparable & x ) const;
            bool isEmpty( ) const;
            void printTree( ) const;

            void makeEmpty( );
            void insert( const Comparable & x );
            void remove( const Comparable & x );

            const BinarySearchTree & operator=( const BinarySearchTree & rhs );

          private:
            BinaryNode<Comparable> *root;
            const Comparable ITEM_NOT_FOUND;

            const Comparable & elementAt( BinaryNode<Comparable> *t ) const;

            void insert( const Comparable & x, BinaryNode<Comparable> * & t ) const;
            void remove( const Comparable & x, BinaryNode<Comparable> * & t ) const;
            BinaryNode<Comparable> * findMin( BinaryNode<Comparable> *t ) const;
            BinaryNode<Comparable> * findMax( BinaryNode<Comparable> *t ) const;
            BinaryNode<Comparable> * find( const Comparable & x, BinaryNode<Comparable> *t ) const;
            void makeEmpty( BinaryNode<Comparable> * & t ) const;
            void printTree( BinaryNode<Comparable> *t ) const;
            BinaryNode<Comparable> * clone( BinaryNode<Comparable> *t ) const;
        };

        #include "BinarySearchTree.cpp"
        #endif
```

BinarySearchTree.cpp

```
        #include "BinarySearchTree.h"
        #include <iostream.h>

        /**
         * Implements an unbalanced binary search tree.
         * Note that all "matching" is based on the < method.
         */

        /**
         * Construct the tree.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::BinarySearchTree( const Comparable & notFound ) :
          root( NULL ), ITEM_NOT_FOUND( notFound )
        {
        }


        /**
         * Copy constructor.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::
        BinarySearchTree( const BinarySearchTree<Comparable> & rhs ) :
          root( NULL ), ITEM_NOT_FOUND( rhs.ITEM_NOT_FOUND )
        { 
            *this = rhs;
        }

        /**
         * Destructor for the tree.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::~BinarySearchTree( )
        {
            makeEmpty( );
        }

        /**
         * Insert x into the tree; duplicates are ignored.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::insert( const Comparable & x )
        {
            insert( x, root );
        }

        /**
         * Remove x from the tree. Nothing is done if x is not found.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::remove( const Comparable & x )
        {
            remove( x, root );
        }


        /**
         * Find the smallest item in the tree.
         * Return smallest item or ITEM_NOT_FOUND if empty.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        const Comparable & BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::findMin( ) const
        {
            return elementAt( findMin( root ) );
        }

        /**
         * Find the largest item in the tree.
         * Return the largest item of ITEM_NOT_FOUND if empty.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        const Comparable & BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::findMax( ) const
        {
            return elementAt( findMax( root ) );
        }

        /**
         * Find item x in the tree.
         * Return the matching item or ITEM_NOT_FOUND if not found.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        const Comparable & BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::
                                 find( const Comparable & x ) const
        {
            return elementAt( find( x, root ) );
        }

        /**
         * Make the tree logically empty.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::makeEmpty( )
        {
            makeEmpty( root );
        }

        /**
         * Test if the tree is logically empty.
         * Return true if empty, false otherwise.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        bool BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::isEmpty( ) const
        {
            return root == NULL;
        }

        /**
         * Print the tree contents in sorted order.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::printTree( ) const
        {
            if( isEmpty( ) )
                cout << "Empty tree" << endl;
            else
                printTree( root );
        }

        /**
         * Deep copy.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        const BinarySearchTree<Comparable> &
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::
        operator=( const BinarySearchTree<Comparable> & rhs )
        {
            if( this != &rhs )
            {
                makeEmpty( );
                root = clone( rhs.root );
            }
            return *this;
        }

        /**
         * Internal method to get element field in node t.
         * Return the element field or ITEM_NOT_FOUND if t is NULL.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        const Comparable & BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::
        elementAt( BinaryNode<Comparable> *t ) const
        {
            if( t == NULL )
                return ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
            else
                return t->element;
        }

        /**
         * Internal method to insert into a subtree.
         * x is the item to insert.
         * t is the node that roots the tree.
         * Set the new root.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::
        insert( const Comparable & x, BinaryNode<Comparable> * & t ) const
        {
            if( t == NULL )
                t = new BinaryNode<Comparable>( x, NULL, NULL );
            else if( x < t->element )
                insert( x, t->left );
            else if( t->element < x )
                insert( x, t->right );
            else
                ;  // Duplicate; do nothing
        }

        /**
         * Internal method to remove from a subtree.
         * x is the item to remove.
         * t is the node that roots the tree.
         * Set the new root.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::
        remove( const Comparable & x, BinaryNode<Comparable> * & t ) const
        {
            if( t == NULL )
                return;   // Item not found; do nothing
            if( x < t->element )
                remove( x, t->left );
            else if( t->element < x )
                remove( x, t->right );
            else if( t->left != NULL && t->right != NULL ) // Two children
            {
                t->element = findMin( t->right )->element;
                remove( t->element, t->right );
            }
            else
            {
                BinaryNode<Comparable> *oldNode = t;
                t = ( t->left != NULL ) ? t->left : t->right;
                delete oldNode;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Internal method to find the smallest item in a subtree t.
         * Return node containing the smallest item.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        BinaryNode<Comparable> *
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::findMin( BinaryNode<Comparable> *t ) const
        {
            if( t == NULL )
                return NULL;
            if( t->left == NULL )
                return t;
            return findMin( t->left );
        }

        /**
         * Internal method to find the largest item in a subtree t.
         * Return node containing the largest item.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        BinaryNode<Comparable> *
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::findMax( BinaryNode<Comparable> *t ) const
        {
            if( t != NULL )
                while( t->right != NULL )
                    t = t->right;
            return t;
        }

        /**
         * Internal method to find an item in a subtree.
         * x is item to search for.
         * t is the node that roots the tree.
         * Return node containing the matched item.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        BinaryNode<Comparable> *
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::
        find( const Comparable & x, BinaryNode<Comparable> *t ) const
        {
            if( t == NULL )
                return NULL;
            else if( x < t->element )
                return find( x, t->left );
            else if( t->element < x )
                return find( x, t->right );
            else
                return t;    // Match
        }
/****** NONRECURSIVE VERSION*************************
        template <class Comparable>
        BinaryNode<Comparable> *
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::
        find( const Comparable & x, BinaryNode<Comparable> *t ) const
        {
            while( t != NULL )
                if( x < t->element )
                    t = t->left;
                else if( t->element < x )
                    t = t->right;
                else
                    return t;    // Match

            return NULL;   // No match
        }
*****************************************************/

        /**
         * Internal method to make subtree empty.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::
        makeEmpty( BinaryNode<Comparable> * & t ) const
        {
            if( t != NULL )
            {
                makeEmpty( t->left );
                makeEmpty( t->right );
                delete t;
            }
            t = NULL;
        }

        /**
         * Internal method to print a subtree rooted at t in sorted order.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::printTree( BinaryNode<Comparable> *t ) const
        {
            if( t != NULL )
            {
                printTree( t->left );
                cout << t->element << endl;
                printTree( t->right );
            }
        }

        /**
         * Internal method to clone subtree.
         */
        template <class Comparable>
        BinaryNode<Comparable> *
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::clone( BinaryNode<Comparable> * t ) const
        {
            if( t == NULL )
                return NULL;
            else
                return new BinaryNode<Comparable>( t->element, clone( t->left ), clone( t->right ) );
        }
```

Comment: Why are you including cpp at the end of your .h?

Comment: which line the error points to? tell us the line/code which the error message points to.

Comment: @geekazoid Because the language requires it.

Comment: @nawaz its everytime i declare a function the first one is at line 13 and from then on its the same error for each subsequent declared function.

Comment: Once I fix the headers, your code compiles fine for me.

Comment: Note, however, that `<iostream.h>` doesn't exist any more, and that it's not the header you include for `NULL`; that would be `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: @tpar44: You're saying `line 13` as if I can know which line is line 13, in the quoted code. Why don't you read your post from our perspective? How would we know which line is line 13 until you explicitly indicate it?

Comment: @JamesKanze You're right. By the ways, it's not "standard" to do such thing of including a .cpp from a .h. It's more common to define it all at the .h; or define it entirely in the .cpp if you only instantiate some specializations of your template class.

Comment: @geekazoid What's "standard" depends on the context.  It's not usual to name the file with the template implementations ".cpp": things like ".tcc" or some other house specific extension are more common.  But as soon as the project gets beyond one or two people, the implementations are carefully moved out of the visible header.  (In the past, often with the hope of easily migrating to `export`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To template a class you don't have to define your functions in your .h files. You can't define them in a .cpp file either. How I have always done it is by defining the templated class in the .h file like you normally do. And then writing the function definitions in a .hpp file.

The .h file would be written like this:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

template<typename T> class MyClass
{
 public:
    int MyFunction();
}
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#endif
```

Make sure you include the .hpp file in your .h file and not the other way around.

Then you're .hpp file will be like this:

```
template<typename T>
int MyClass::MyFunction()
{
    ...
}
```

Make sure you scope the function, and DON'T include the .h file in the .hpp. The compiler will get mad at you.

This is essentially the same as defining the function inside the .h file but this allows you to keep two seperate files. If you're class is small with very few functions or most of the functions are one liners ie. getter/setter functions. It might not be worth making a whole nother file for that, but in cases like BST and AVL it is very nice to have multiple files so you aren't staring at a wall of code.

Comment: Those are just naming conventions.  I come from a Unix world, somewhat influenced by g++, and my "header" files end in `.hh`, with the actual implementation of the template in a `.tcc`.  Others have other conventions, but there's certainly nothing wrong with defining the template functions in a `.cpp`, provided you don't try to compile it, and the include of the header in the `.cpp` doesn't do any harm; the include guards ensure that.

Comment: Yes, now I understand the #inlcude .cpp is at the bottom.  Its so that you only include the .h files in the driver program and the compiler links the others so to speak.  Thanks this did the trick.  Just so you know, i did keep it as a .cpp and it works fine as long as i dont try to compile the .cpp twice